# How can I apply a css rule to all descendants of an elements 

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can you redefine a class if its in another specific class?

```
div.cls {
color:blue;
}

div.tst > div.cls {
color:red;
}

<div class="cls">test</div> // text color = blue

<div class="tst">
  <div class="cls">test</div> // text color = red
  <div>
    <div class="cls">test</div> // text color = blue
  </div>
<div>
```

How to make the last one also red?

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gpD7H/

Comment: Your code should work fine.  What are you asking?

Comment: Whats your question exactly? Is there something there that doesn't have the color you expected?

Comment: also if the `cls` class isn't directly a child to the `tst`?

Comment: as said in the asnwers then, just change from "child" (>) selector to descendant selector (nothing in between).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the [*descendant selector* <sup>[W3C]</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors): `div.tst  div.cls`

`>` is the [*child selector* <sup>[W3C]</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) and will only match children of an element.

Answer (score 48):

I used this, it work for me:

```css
.name-of-parent * { color: red; }
```

Comment: Works perfectly and saves a lot of time

Answer (score 6):

Exactly like that. However, your second division *won't* be red text because it's also contained within another division. The `>` selector only matches to the immediate children under the element matched before it, so it's looking inside `div.tst` at only one level. Try removing the `>` from the selector:

```
div.tst div.cls {
color:red;
}
```

[Your updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpD7H/1/)