# Changing the list-style-type of a li elements in a nested table of contents

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a rule:

```
    .table-of-contents > ol > li {
      list-style-type: lower-latin;
    }
```

However it only selects the `li` elements at the first level of the table of contents.  The table of contents could have nested levels like this:

```
    <ol>
        <li>l1
            <ol>
                <li>l2</li>
            </ol>
         </li>
    </ol>
```

Is there a way to select all the li elements within the container `<nav class="table-of-contents"> toc structure ...</nav>`

[Based on the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css) I think it might be

```
.table-of-contents * {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Sound about right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply a css rule to all descendants of an elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749466/how-can-i-apply-a-css-rule-to-all-descendants-of-an-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change that selector to `.table-of-contents ol li  { ... }`, without the `>` which restricts it to direct descendants.

Comment: Ah brilliant - Thanks!